# Correct Basic Authentication in HttpClient 4.3.x

Tags: java, authentication, httpclient

I currently use the following basic authentication implementation:

```
        HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(uri);

        // Set the basic authentication
        httpGet.addHeader(BasicScheme.authenticate(
                new UsernamePasswordCredentials("user", "pass"),
                "UTF-8", false));

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
        HttpEntity entity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        ...
```

The code works fine however `BasicScheme.authenticate` is deprecated.

What is the correct way to implement the basic authentication for a request in HttpClient 4.3.x?

Comment: Nobody has any idea how to do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works for me -

```
    HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(uri);

    // Set the basic authentication
    String encoding = Base64Encoder.encode("user:pass");
    httpGet.setHeader("Authorization", "Basic" + encoding);

    HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
    HttpEntity entity = httpResponse.getEntity();
```

Please let me know if it works fine for you.

Comment: Thank you. It worked fine for me also and I've got rid of the deprecated API.

Comment: @Mythul Glad to know.